# Is it acceptable to post the same question on multiple sites?

Tags: discussion, policy, cross-posting

For example, if I want to reach a wider audience of potential answerers, is it acceptable to post the same question here, as well as on mathoverflow, and other sites that come up that are relevant?  Or is that considered a mild form of spamming?

Comment: Have you read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: I went back to read it again, and, yes, this time I caught the line: "Please note, however, that cross-posting is not encouraged."  I missed it my first two times reading through -- it was not where I expected it to be.  I apologize.

Comment: related http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/stackexchange-mathematics-vs-cross-validated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: No]. This is making chaos and irritates the answerers.

If you are sure that the question is relevant on two SEs, it probably can be split in two separate parts with a gain in clarity.

If you are not sure which place is more adequate, try on one site and let its community decide whether to keep it or migrate to a more suitable site.

Comment: +1 for emphasis.

Comment: An outright "No" is contrary to the "not encouraged" rule. If a question goes unanswered, wouldn't reaching a new userbase of users who may be more interested, or have more knowledge help to solve the question? The fact there is significant overlap between stats and maths (well technically, the former is a subset of the latter) make this even more relevant. I believe in unification, but it would be easy to cross-reference between the two sites within the question, and then maybe combine it all into one at the end.